# Select elements from 2D list with stride "t"

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to select elements from 2D list according to variable position (i.e. stride). For example:

```
x=Range@25 ~Partition~ 5
```

I want a command to select elements with stride `t=2` as `y={{1,3,5},{11,13,15},{21,23,25}}`. Simply, take one and leave one. What if t=3,4,...etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
t = 2;
Partition[Range[25], 5][[;; ;; t, ;; ;; t]]
```

> {{1, 3, 5}, {11, 13, 15}, {21, 23, 25}}

Or, as suggested by J.M.issomewhatokey, use `Take`:

```
Take[Partition[Range[25], 5], {1, -1, t}, {1, -1, t}]
```

> {{1, 3, 5}, {11, 13, 15}, {21, 23, 25}}

```
Partition[Range[25], 5][[;; ;; 3, ;; ;; 3]]
```

> {{1, 4}, {16, 19}}

Comment: `Take[]` ought to work here, too.

Comment: @J.M. yes it does. Thank, you.

Comment: Thanks :) it works well...

Comment: @AlienTsukuba, you are most welcome.